# Torque cross product

Tags: forces, vectors, conventions, torque

Torque is the cross product of force and distance.  Almost all the resources I find online have the formula as $\vec\tau=\vec d\times \vec F$, yet my professor (and I've seen some other sources do this) insists on using $\vec\tau=\vec F\times \vec d$.  From what I've learned, swapping the two vectors in the cross product gives a vector of same magnitude but in the opposite direction.  This gives a different answer, so which one is supposed to be used?

Comment: You may believe Wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque in this regard. Further, cite at least one resource which says that $\vec \tau=\vec F\times \vec d$ instead of $\vec \tau=\vec d\times \vec F$

Comment: Does your professor also define angular momentum as $\vec{L}=\vec{p}\times\vec{d}$ rather than $\vec{L}=\vec{d}\times\vec{p}$? If so, it’s consistent but rather eccentric.

Answer (score 1):

$\vec \tau=\vec r \times  \vec F$ is consistent with the right-hand grip / right-hand corkscrew rule.

[image]